# Remove object from array based on remove array in Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I want to remove all the objects from the users array coming in remove array. Please correct my DataWeave code mentioned below. Expected output is also mentioned.

```
            %dw 2.0
            output application/json
            var remove =[
            {
            "startDate": "2022-04-13",
            "objectName": "Account"
            }
            ]
            var users = [{
                    "startDate": 20220412,
                    "objectName": "Account"
                },
                {
                    "startDate": 20220412,
                    "objectName": "Blanket Agreemt"
                }
            ]
            ---
            users filter ((item, index) -> item.objectName != value.objectName) map (value, key) -> {
                "objectName": value.objectName
            }
```

Expected output:

```
            [{
                "startDate": 20220412,
                "objectName": "Blanket Agreemt"
            }]
```

Comment: What is the issue with your script? What is exactly the objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter is invalid and the issue unclear. I'll do an educated guess that the objective is to return all elements from the list which their objectName is also present in one of the objects in `remove`. The map() at the end doesn't seems to be needed.

To resolve we can collect all objectNames into a list with the [multi-value selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors#multi_value_selector) (`remove.*objectName`) and use [contains()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-contains) function to check if the current element of `users` exists in the `remove` array. Finally the `not()` is needed to complete the condition for the `filter`.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var remove =[
    {
        "startDate": "2022-04-13",
        "objectName": "Account"
    }
]
var users = [
    {
        "startDate": 20220412,
        "objectName": "Account"
    },
    {
        "startDate": 20220412,
        "objectName": "Blanket Agreemt"
    }
]
---
users 
    filter ((item, index) -> not (remove.*objectName contains ( item.objectName)))
```

Comment: and if I had to filter with 2 conditions or more ? I'm not able to achieve it.

Comment: @CarLoOSX please open a question with the details.

Comment: Sorry, at the end I found the way to do it : fun noMatchingFromTo(array1, array2) = array1 filter (item, index) -> not ((array2.*name contains ( item.name)) and (array2.*"type" contains ( item."type"))).   Thank you :)

Comment: Again that should have gone into its own question.